# Understanding the Confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, spss

I'm trying to figure this out and either I am completely missing the point or I am in fact correct. (I am a student).

The null hypothesis is "There is no significant difference between time taken to complete a booking between the two group, new users and previous users".

It is my understanding that to reject this I need a 95% CI that doesn't lie within 0. However from the image below it does {-25.47, 4.65}. But the p value is .172 which accepts the null. I cant seem to find online what I am not understanding? Do i accept it from the 95% CI or have I got something misunderstood?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example]

Comment: I think you need to include the `self-study` tag on this one mate.

Comment: Properly, your null hypothesis should be a statement about a population (as should your alternative); the word "significant" doesn't belong in a hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the two groups, which can be inferred from the fact that 0 is included in the confidence interval. Therefore, we have no evidence against the null hypothesis, which is that there is no difference between the groups.

Comment: Thanks - I've also just realized I was thinking that for 5% it was a p less that 0.05 and not 0.5! You may be able to tell math is not my strong point!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help - we all start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what André stated.  There is not a significant difference between groups.  Both the confidence interval (which contains zero) and the result of the t test, *t*(56) = -1.286, *p* = .204 indicate a failure to reject the null hypothesis.

I do want to add one thing, with a t-test, we either reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.  We are not able to accept it.  It may sound a bit particular, but it is an important distinction to make.